# Managed metadata column in SharePoint 2013

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, nintex-workflow

How can I get value of managed metadata column's value and corresponding change event using jQuery? I'm working with Nintex forms and requirement is to read the selected value.

Regards,
Vikrant

Comment: I'm not familiar with the nintex piece, but are you just trying to track when a column (that you would be monitoring via jQuery) changes its value?

Comment: Can you specify what precisely doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Managed Metdata column should have the following: "Store Client ID in JavaScript variable" set to "Yes". JavaScript ID can be anything, e.g. CtrlName

Using the variable defined above in Form Custom JavaScript add:

```
NWF$("#" + CtrlName).bind('change', function(event) {
  var result = NWF$("#" + CtrlName).val(); 
});
```